# How to shuffle a vector of objects in c++

Tags: c++, std, shuffle

I'm new to c++ programming and trying to make a blackjack game with a view of getting the logic working and then using some of the code to make a graphical version.

My code is below and Visual Studio states no issues found, but when I try and compile the code, I get the following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2672   'swap': no matching overloaded function found   blackJack   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\utility   78

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>

class card
{
public:
    std::string suite;
    char pictureCard = 'n';
    int value = 0;
    const int numberOfDecks = 1;
    void setCardValue(const int& value, std::string suite, char pictureCard);
    void getDeck();
    void setDeck(const int& numberOfDecks);

    void shuffle();
    std::vector <card> v;
};

void::card::setCardValue(const int& value, std::string suite, char pictureCard)
{
    this->value = value;
    this->suite = suite;
    this->pictureCard = pictureCard;
}

void::card::setDeck(const int& numberOfDecks) 
{
    card c1;
    for (int n = 0; n < numberOfDecks; n++)
    { 
        int j = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) //set Numbered cards
        {
            c1.setCardValue(j, "Hearts", 'N');
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(j, "Clubs", 'N');
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(j, "Diamonds", 'N');
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(j, "Spades", 'N');
            v.push_back(c1);
            j++;
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++) //set Pictured cards
        {
            char N = 'N';
            if (p == 0) { N = 'J'; }
            else if (p == 1) { N = 'Q'; }
            else if (p == 2) { N = 'K'; }
            else if (p == 3) { N = 'A'; };

            c1.setCardValue(10, "Hearts", N);
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(10, "Clubs", N);
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(10, "Diamonds", N);
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(10, "Spades", N);
            v.push_back(c1);
        }
    }

    int seed = 1;
    std::default_random_engine e(seed);


    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), e);


}

void card::getDeck()
{
    for (auto it = begin(v); it != end(v); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->value << it->suite << it->pictureCard << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;


}



int main()
{
    card c2;
    c2.setDeck(6);
    c2.getDeck();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Apologies in advance if this is a really basic error, but can't seem to figure it out as my debugging skills are basic as well.

Comment: Edit your question with the full compiler error (see console), not the single line from the problem list.

Comment: the `shuffle` algorithm uses `std::swap` internally. You need to implement a specialization of `std::swap` for your `card` See here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle
"RandomIt must meet the requirements of ValueSwappable and LegacyRandomAccessIterator."

Comment: Did you mean to write `void card::setCardValue` instead of `void::card::setCardValue` etc?

Comment: As secondary issue (see answer below for primary issue):  `class card` containing `std::vector <card> v;` is strange might also break any sorting.  You probably want a `class DeckOfCards` to hold the collection and do the shuffling.

Comment: Seems to me there are two classes here: a `card` class and a `deck` class. Even if there's only one deck, a deck isn't a card. Don't know I that will resolve the problem here, though.

Comment: Your `card` class is poorly designed. Instead of thinking 'what is a card?' (e.g. a suit and a numerical value) you seem to have stuffed everything card related into one class, Since that includes stuff that should be in a different class (like a `deck` class as Pete mentioned) you are getting into trouble when you try to manipulate individual cards (like swapping them during a shuffle). So add a new class or classes and move everything from the `card` class that isn't strictly related to an individual card to those new classes. Probably a total rewrite is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look a few lines above and below the error message your compiler should tell which line in your program resulted in the cascade of errors:

```
t.C:76:17:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:182:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘swap(card&, card&)’
  182 |       swap(*__a, *__b);
```

Line 76 is the call to `std::shuffle`.

```
 const int numberOfDecks = 1;
```

Your `card` class has a non-static `const` member. That automatically removes the default assignment and move operators from the class. You can't assign one `card` to another, by default, just like that, because that would mean -- by definition -- that one object's `const` member gets mysteriously replaced by another object's member's value. As Mr. Spock would say: "this is not logical".

You'll either need to remove the `const` class member or define your own `operator=` overload for the `card` class that does whatever makes sense for `=` to do, with your `card` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the responses. They were all really helpful - I have a lot to learn but I'm finding it fun!

Sam Varshavchik your answer worked first time. As soon as I removed the const class member the program compiled without error.

I have also taken everyone's comments regarding class design on board and I have come up with the following solution below that works perfectly. I will now have some fun working on dealing functions etc.

Many thanks again.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>


class card
{
public:
    std::string suite;
    char pictureCard = 'n';
    int value = 0;
    void setCardValue(const int& value, std::string suite, char pictureCard);
};

void::card::setCardValue(const int& value, std::string suite, char pictureCard)
{
    this->value = value;
    this->suite = suite;
    this->pictureCard = pictureCard;
}


class deck
{
public:
    const int numberOfDecks = 1;
    void setDeck(const int& numberOfDecks);
    std::vector <card> v;   
};

void::deck::setDeck(const int& numberOfDecks)
{
    card c1;
    for (int n = 0; n < numberOfDecks; n++)
    {
        int j = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) //set Numbered cards
        {
            c1.setCardValue(j, "Hearts", 'N');
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(j, "Clubs", 'N');
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(j, "Diamonds", 'N');
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(j, "Spades", 'N');
            v.push_back(c1);
            j++;
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++) //set Pictured cards
        {
            char N = 'N';
            if (p == 0) { N = 'J'; }
            else if (p == 1) { N = 'Q'; }
            else if (p == 2) { N = 'K'; }
            else if (p == 3) { N = 'A'; };

            c1.setCardValue(10, "Hearts", N);
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(10, "Clubs", N);
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(10, "Diamonds", N);
            v.push_back(c1);
            c1.setCardValue(10, "Spades", N);
            v.push_back(c1);
        }
    }
}


class dealer
{
public:
    void shuffle(deck &deck);
    void getDeck(deck &deck);
};

void::dealer::shuffle(deck &deck)
{
    auto e = std::default_random_engine{};
    std::shuffle(deck.v.begin(), deck.v.end(), e);
}

void::dealer::getDeck(deck &deck)
{
    for (auto it = begin(deck.v); it != end(deck.v); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->value << it->suite << it->pictureCard << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << deck.v.size() << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    deck deck;
    dealer dealer;
    deck.setDeck(6);
    dealer.shuffle(deck);
    dealer.getDeck(deck);

    return 0;
}
```